# Update manager finds updates but `apt update` doesn't

Tags: linux, updates, apt

In Linux Mint 19.1 I found a kernel update in update manager but when I checked in terminal by the command:

```
sudo apt update
```

I didn't find anything. When I refreshed update manager it still shows the update. Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 2):

For any Ubuntu/Debian based system:

> You should first run `update`, then `upgrade`. Neither of them automatically runs the other.
>
> - `apt-get update` updates the list of available packages and their versions, but it does not install or upgrade any packages.
> - `apt-get upgrade` actually installs newer versions of the packages you have. After updating the lists, the package manager knows about available updates for the software you have installed. This is why you first want to update.

Source: [*What is the difference between `apt-get update` and `upgrade`?*](https://askubuntu.com/a/94104)

This also applies to `apt`. See [*What is the difference between `apt` and `apt-get`?*](https://askubuntu.com/q/445384)

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski You're correct. I've edited my post.